# Delphi: Why A class variable affects the result of the method?

Tags: delphi

This is a full simplification of my code, but even so it doesn't work when class var ID_COUNTER is there, in this code I don't use the class var, but in my real code yes, but just the existence of this class variable
makes the result of 's' different.  This is the most weird I have ever seen.

Here is a simplification, but still doesn't Works, one Unit in 75 lines.

```
 unit Umain;
 interface
 uses
 Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,     Vcl.StdCtrls,XMLIntf,XmlDoc,IOUtils,XMLDom,System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TStore = class
  public
   class var ID_COUNTER: Integer;
   MainNode: IDomNode;
  constructor create(node:IDomNode);
   function getNode():IDomNode;
 end;
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
 FMain: TStore;
   function Recursive(node:IDomNode):TStore;

 end;

 var
    Form1: TForm1;

 implementation

 {$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc:IXMLDocument;
  content: WideString;
  html: IDomNode;
  s: String;
 begin
    Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
    Doc.LoadFromFile('C:\temp\example.xml');
    Doc.Active := true;
    html := Doc.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('html').item[0];
    FMain := Recursive(html);
    s := FMain.getNode().nodeName;
 end;

 function TForm1.Recursive(node: IDOMNode):TStore;
 var
   i: Integer;
   store: TStore;
  nodeName,nodeValue:String;
 begin
   store := TStore.create(node);

  if(not node.hasChildNodes)then
    Exit(store);

   for i := 0 to node.childNodes.length-1 do
   begin
     Recursive(node.childNodes.item[i]);
   end;

  Exit(store);
end;
constructor TStore.create(node: IDOMNode);
begin
  self.MainNode := node;
end;
function TStore.getNode:IDomNode;
begin
  Result := self.MainNode;
end;

end.
```

Some notes:

example.xml is only a simple HTML document.
Everything is broken when ID_COUNTER exists, if it is commented, everything is Ok. It happens here and in my real and wide Project.

Comment: An unused class var can only influence behaviour if your code is broken in some other way. Eg reads ininitialized memory. Please show SSCCE. Otherwise there's no actionable question.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answering the question, I am new here and I do not what Do yo mean with SSCCE, May I update some Small Project ?

Comment: You can use websearch to see the sscce means

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I am with Delphi XE5, maybe that helps.

Comment: Unused class vars have no impact in all versions. Time for that sscce. Learning how to make an sscce is step 1 of learning how to debug.

Comment: @user3779155: http://www.acronymfinder.com/SSCCE.html, definitions 2 or 3, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that, syntactically, `class var` introduces a class field *block* rather than a single class field, meaning that if you use `class var`, all following field declarations in the same visibility section will be class variables too. **So now, `MainNode` becomes a class variable too** and that probably causes the problems you encounter. Reformatting your code shows this a little more clearly:

```
public
  class var 
    ID_COUNT: Integer;
    MainNode: IDomNode;
  constructor Create(... etc.
```

Your options are:

- move `ID_COUNT` one line down:

  ```
  public
    MainNode: IDomNode;
    class var ID_COUNTER: Integer;
    constructor Create(... etc.
  ```
- create a special section for `MainNode`:

  ```
  public
    class var ID_COUNTER: Integer;
  public
    MainNode: IDomNode;
    constructor Create(... etc.
  ```
- preface `MainNode` with the `var` keyword (which, likewise, introduces a *block*, specifically an instance field block within the current visibility section):

  ```
  public
    class var 
      ID_COUNTER: Integer;
      // any other class variables
    var 
      MainNode: IDomNode;
      // any other instance variables
    constructor Create(... etc.
  ```

Comment: You can use plain `var` also to introduce instance var. Good spot. +1

Comment: After spend two days trying for a solution, google-ing during hours, at the end I found the problem. Yes, a not used class variable can affect your code, if someone checks my code can verify this. The solution too simple change the order of the class variable, just put after the other variables and not before. I wonder myself if delphi should not be throw a warning in this situation and allow you that your code fails.

Comment: So now it is solved, I have to do something with the thread ?

Comment: Not sure know if may edit is too radical, sorry if it is and then feel free to edit/rollback as necessary. Just wanted to line up all the options, including @David's, in a nice way.

Comment: @user - Why would the compiler warn you? It's perfectly possible you might be having more than one class vars on purpose.

Comment: @user3779155 An unused class variable cannot alter behaviour. But that wasn't the problem. Like you I did not spot that what you were actually doing was changing an instance variable to a class variable.

Comment: @AndriyM: although I generally don't like my answers to be edited, this was a good one. It is more readable and provides one extra solution. Thanks!

Comment: Collaboration to improve answers is why SO is such a good forum. Whether it is from comments, new answers or editing other answers, it is all for the benefit of the users.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You should like your answers being edited. I like them being edited. Probably >95% of the edits to my answers make them better. That's a good thing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am with you here. While I don't have that many answers, I haven't had one bad edit on any of my answers. I have had a few edits by Remy that were a huge improvement over the original answer.

Comment: @Gray Yes, Remy in particular is a very good editor. He's made many very good edits to my answers.

Comment: @david: I know that SO is different. I merely explained why I am not used to (and not particularly fond of) edits, in general.